# The width of the shelf minus the sum of the boxes widths inside it >= the width of the new box

Tags: java

I have a warehouse project I can create boxes with length, width and height and create shelves with length width height too. And I have an option to add that box to this shelf but I want to compare that the length, width and height of the box are smaller or equals the shelves `(L, W, H)` but for width has to be like this `w - w2 >= w3`, so I want to count it but I don't know how to find the sum of the already added boxes widths inside the shelf.

- `w` = the width of the shelf
- `w2` = the sum of the already added boxes widths inside the shelf
- `w3` = the width of the new box

I am really beginner in java and need help please. this is the code so far I did for comparing:

```
private boolean fitsIntoShelf(int place, Box box) {
    int w = getwidth()-"the sum of the boxes widths inside it";

    if (this.getlength() >= box.getLength() && w >= box.getWidth() && this.getheight() >= box.getHeight()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Shelf class code:

```
package de.majed.warehouse;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Shelf {
    // the array of boxes stored in the shelf
    private Box[] places;

    // The properties of the shelf.
    // size of the shelf
    private int capacity = 10;
    private int length, width, height;
    private String ID;

    /**
     * 
     * @param capacity
     * @param newid
     */
    public Shelf(int cap, int newlength, int newwidth, int newheight, String newid) {
        //
        this.capacity = cap;
        places = new Box[this.capacity];
        setlength(newlength);
        setwidth(newwidth);
        setheight(newheight);
        setid(newid);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Shelf(int newlength, int newwidth, int newheight, String newid) {

        setlength(newlength);
        setwidth(newwidth);
        setheight(newheight);
        setid(newid);
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return places.length;
    }

    public String getid() {
        return ID;
    }

    private void setid(String newid) {
        ID = newid;
    }

    public int getlength() {
        return length;
    }

    private void setlength(int newlength) {
        length = newlength;
    }

    public int getwidth() {
        return width;
    }

    private void setwidth(int newwidth) {
        width = newwidth;
    }

    public int getheight() {
        return height;
    }

    private void setheight(int newheight) {
        height = newheight;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param place
     * @return
     */
    public Box getContentOf(int place) {
        return places[place];
    }

    //

    /**
     * Add box if a place empty.
     * 
     * @param box
     *            The Box which should be added
     */
    public void addBox(Box box) {
        /*
         * check one time if box fits into shelf. if not >>>
         * JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
         * "The box is bigger than the shelf.");
         **/
        for (int f = 0; f < places.length; f++) {
            if (fitsIntoShelf(f, box)) {

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The box is bigger than the shelf.");
                break;
            }
            // check if there isa an empty place. if not
            // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No place found in the
            // shelf.");

            if (isPlaceEmpty(f)) {
                places[f] = box;
                return;
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No place found in the shelf.");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Add the box if the place is empty.
     * 
     * @param place
     * @param box
     */
    public void putBoxTo(int place, Box box) {
        if (isPlaceEmpty(place)) {
            places[place] = box;
        } else {
            // Message to user
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("There is no empty place");
        }
    }

    // Check if place is empty.
    public boolean isPlaceEmpty(int place) {

        if (places[place] == null) {

            return true;

        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean fitsIntoShelf(int place, Box box) {

        if (this.getlength() >= box.getLength() && this.getwidth() >= box.getWidth() && this.getheight() >= box.getHeight())

            return true;
        else {

            return false;
        }
    }

    // return index if found otherwise -1

    /**
     * 
     * @param box
     * @return the index of the box, -1 if not found
     */
    public int findBox(Box box, Shelf str) {

        for (int i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {

            if (places[i].equals(box)) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The item has been found in: | "  +  str  +  " | ");

            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        // To show the list of the shelves and the boxes inside it.
        String str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
            if (!isPlaceEmpty(i)) {
                str += places[i].toString() + "; ";
            }
        }
        return "Shelf [ " + getid() + " ] >>>" + " boxes in shelf:" + str;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Shelf))
            return false;
        Shelf b = (Shelf) obj;
        if (b == null)
            return false;
        if (this.ID == null)
            return b.ID == null;
        return this.ID.equals(b.getid());
    }

}
```

Box class code:

```
package de.majed.warehouse;

public class Box {
    // The properties of the Box
    private int Length, Width, Height;
    private String id;

    public Box() {

    }

    // To set the new properties values.
    public Box(int newLength, int newWidth, int newHeight, String newID) {
        setLength(newLength);
        setWidth(newWidth);
        setHeight(newHeight);
        setID(newID);
    }

    public Box(Box newWidth) {

    }

    public int getLength() {
        return Length;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return Width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return Height;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    private void setLength(int newLength) {
        Length = newLength;
    }

    private void setWidth(int newWidth) {
        Width = newWidth;
    }

    private void setHeight(int newHeight) {
        Height = newHeight;
    }

    private void setID(String newID) {
        id = newID;
    }

    @Override
    // To get the list of the new added boxes with their properties values.
    public String toString() {
        return "Box ID: " + getID() + " (L: " + getLength() + " - W: " + getWidth() + " - H: " + getHeight() + ")";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!(obj instanceof Box))
            return false;
        Box b = (Box) obj;
        if (b == null)
            return false;
        if (this.id == null)
            return b.id == null;
        return this.id.equals(b.getID());
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know actually, I have the code of the Box class and Shelf class and they want from me to make this code that the box which I want to add to the shelf must not be bigger than the remaining space of the shelf.                        can you help me in this please?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest solution is to add a new property to Shelf called "availableWidth". Every time a box gets added to a shelf, you subtract the width of that box from availableWidth. In other words, it would be done in your addBox method. Then when you're writing your fitsIntoShelf method, you can just call getAvailableWidth() assuming you write a getter for it. Also, I'm wondering why you're passing in an int for place into the fitsIntoShelf() method since you're not doing anything with it. Not a huge deal, but it just seems to be dead code.